# Should question's title have inside parenthesis the view it's looking for?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

If a question is expecting view of a particular sect should it mention so inside parenthesis in the title that what view it is expecting?

If not, then what else is suggested to be done?

*Reasoning required*

Comment: A clear indication in the body add a well written question will do anyway and correct tagging should take care of this. Nothing is particularly wrong with having it in the subject but it is a bit cluttering after a while and should not be required, at most allowed if the OP prefers it so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I would say no; formatting titles in that way effectively just treats the requested view as a tag, and we already have tags to do that job.  It would be better on principle to just include it in natural-language.  Take the following two examples:

1. What is the ruling on such-and-such? (Shi'a view)
2. What is the Shi'a ruling on such-and-such?

Not only is the second one (slightly) shorter, but it also puts more emphasis on the fact that it's actually a *Shi'a* ruling that's requested.  The first one, it feels like the requested view is more of an afterthought than an integral part of the question; I suspect that many people would read the *question* (i.e. the sentence that ends with a question mark) and be inclined to skip over the parenthetical entirely.

Grammatically speaking, a parenthesis is something that can be removed from a sentence without (significantly) changing the meaning, while still leaving it grammatically correct; it effectively acts as a *de-emphasisis*, which is useful for adding transient information or clarification, but it shouldn't be used to house *critical* information.  If removing it from the question title fundamentally changes the question, it is being used incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Might you don't do this please? If you put it in parenthesis we may lose the viewpoint of others sects. I mean if we have the Shia and Sunni both answers for a question it lets us to improve our knowledge and learning.