# Should we change "What's your Islam-related question? Be specific" to "What do you want to learn about Islam? Ask a specific question"?

Tags: feature-request, questions

I propose changing:

> What's your Islam-related question? Be specific.

to

> What do you want to learn about Islam?  Ask a specific question.

This occurs in a gray font when we [ask a question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/ask):

[image: What's your Islam-related question? Be specific.]

I think it's better because

1. the question should be *about Islam* (not just *related to Islam*);  it makes Islam the focus: we're learning about Islam, and
2. it further highlights how the title should be in the form of a question (not e.g. [Jesus Christ mother](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/47086/17163)).  See [Advice for writing question titles on Islam.SE](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1837/17163).

The main aim is to contribute to reducing "I'm a Muslim with a problem; what do I do?" questions, which are often related to Islam ("my husband said talaq"), but are not about Islam ("what do I do?").

I'm hoping it will nudge some authors to ask about the Islamic parts of their personally motivated problems (what do I need to learn about Islam to solve my problem?).

**Question**: Should we change "What's your Islam-related question? Be specific" to "What do you want to learn about Islam?  Ask a specific question"?

---

For reference, the other religion sites have:

- [Buddhism.SE](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask): What's your Buddhist philosophy, teaching, and practice question? Be specific.
- [Christianity.SE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/ask):  What's your Christianity question?  Be specific.
- [Hinduism.SE](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask):  What's your Hindu religion question?  Be specific.
- [Judaism.SE](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask): What's your Judaism question? Be specific.

Answer (score 3):

I do not see any harm in changing the default text; it may help. We can monitor over time if this has a positive impact on the quality of questions (title and content).